# HTML Form not Updating information after certain number of entries

Tags: php, html, mysql, runtime-error

Included below is all of the PHP script on a page. The page works wonders until one of my users had an issue. They messaged me and said that the edit feature no longer worked. Normally when you click 'update' you are shown a message saying that your wishlist had been updated, but for this user, when they clicked on the update button it just refreshed the page. It is no longer changing the information in the database.

I tried removing a few of the entries from the database itself, and the user was then able to edit. Once they added the creatures back, however it no longer worked, a matter of fact it broke in a different location.

The first time the wishlist update feature broke around 162 creatures, and this time it broke around 168 creatures.

What could be causing this weird glitch? What can I do to fix it? THank you!

```
   <center>
      <code>
        [insert_php]
        // Info to connect to the Wishlist database
        $servername = "secret";
        $dbusername = "secret";
        $password = "supersecret";
        $dbname = "notsosecret";

        try {
            // To connect to the database please
            $conn = new mysqli($servername, $dbusername, $password, $dbname);
            if ($conn->connect_error) {
                die('Connect Error (' . $conn->connect_errno . ') '
                    . $conn->connect_error);
            }

           echo "<font size ='3'><br>Please click <strong><a href = 'http://eggcavity.com/add-wishlist'>here</a></strong> to add creatures to your wishlist.<br><br>Please click <strong><a href='http://eggcavity.com/wishlists'>here</a></strong> to view your wishlist.<br><br>At the moment when you enter notes you cannot view them on the edit page. <br>Please go to the view wishlist page to see your notes.<br><br></font>";

           if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                $ids = $_POST['ids'];
                $theCount = 0;
                // Prepare and bind the udpate statement
                $sql2 = "UPDATE Wishlists SET Picture = ?, Stage = ?, Gender = ?, Frozen = ?, Notes= ? WHERE ID = ?";
                $stmt2 = $conn->prepare($sql2);
                $stmt2->bind_param('sssssi', $picture, $stage, $gender, $frozen, $notes, $id);
                foreach($ids as $id){
                    $stagecode = $id . "stage";
                    $gendercode = $id . "gender";
                    $frozencode = $id . "frozen";
                    $notescode = $id . "notes";
                    $namecode = $id . "creature";
                    $stage = $_POST[$stagecode];
                    $Stage = $stage;
                    $gender = $_POST[$gendercode];
                    $frozen = $_POST[$frozencode];
                    $notes = $_POST[$notescode];
                    $name = $_POST[$namecode];
                    $sql1 = 'SELECT * FROM Creatures WHERE Name = "' . $name . '"';
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
                    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
                    $picture = $row["$stage"];
                    $stmt2->execute();
                }
                if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
                    $delete=!empty( $_POST['delete'] ) ? $_POST['delete'] : false;
                    if($delete && !is_array($delete) ){
                        $delete=explode(',',$delete);
                    }
                    foreach($delete as $id){
                        $sql = "DELETE FROM Wishlists WHERE ID = ?";
                        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
                        $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
                        $stmt->execute();
                        $theCount++;
                     }
                 }
                 echo "<font size='3'>Your wishlist has been updated, and " .$theCount. " creature(s) has/have been removed from your wishlist.<br><br>Please click <u><strong><a href='http://eggcavity.com/edit-wishlist'>here</a></u></strong> to return to the edit page.</href><br><br>";
           } else {
               // Get current user's username
               $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
               $username = $current_user->user_login;
               // Just display the form
               $sql = 'SELECT Creature, Picture, Stage, Gender, Frozen, Notes, ID FROM Wishlists WHERE Username = "' . $username . '"';
               $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
               if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                   $numcreatures = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                   echo '<form method="POST"><table style="border-collapse: collapse";><strong>' .
                       '<tr>' .
                           '<td>' . $numcreatures . ' creatures</td>' .
                           '<td style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:center;">Creature</td>' .
                           '<td style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:center;">Stage</td>' .
                           '<td style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:center;">Gender</td>' .
                           '<td style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:center;">Frozen</td>' .
                       '</tr></strong>';
                   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                       $creature = $row["Creature"];
                       $id = $row["ID"];
                       $picture = $row["Picture"];
                       $stage = $row["Stage"];
                       $sql3 = 'SELECT * FROM Creatures WHERE Name = "' . $creature . '"';
                       $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql3);
                       $row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc();
                       echo '<input name="ids[]" type="hidden" value="' . $id . '">' .
                           '<input name="' . $id . 'creature" type="hidden" value="' . $creature . '">' .
                           '<tr>' .
                               '<td rowspan="2" style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:center;"><img src="' . $picture . '"></td>' .
                               '<td style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:center;">' . $creature . '</td>' .
                               '<td style"border:1px solid gray;text-align:center;"><select name="' . $id . 'stage">' .
                                   '<option value ="' . $stage . '" selected>' . $stage . '</option>' . 
                                   '<option value = "Stage1">Stage1(Egg)</option>' .
                                   '<option value = "Stage2">Stage2</option>';
                                   if ($row2["Stage3"] != "") {
                                       echo '<option value = "Stage3">Stage3</option>';
                                   }
                                   if ($row2["Stage4"] != "") {
                                       echo '<option value = "Stage4">Stage4</option>';
                                   }
                               echo '</select></td>' .
                               '<td style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:center;"><select name="' . $id . 'gender">' .
                                   '<option value ="' . $row["Gender"] . '" selected>' . $row["Gender"] . '</option>' . 
                                   '<option value = "Unspecified">Unspecified</option>' .
                                   '<option value = "Female">Female</option>' .
                                   '<option value = "Male">Male</option>' . 
                               '</select></td>' .
                               '<td style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:center;"><select name="' . $id . 'frozen">' .
                                   '<option value ="' . $row["Frozen"] . '" selected>' . $row["Frozen"] . '</option>' . 
                                   '<option value="Unspecified">Unspecified</option>' .
                                   '<option value="Yes">Yes</option>' .
                                   '<option value="No">No</option>' .
                               '</select></td>' .
                           '</tr>' .
                           '<tr>' .
                               '<td  style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:center;" colspan="3">Notes: <input type="text" name="' . $id . 'notes" value="' . $row["Notes"] .'"></td>' .
                               '<td style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:center;">' . 'Delete<br>' . '<input type="checkbox" name="delete[]" value="' . $id . '"></td>' .
                           '</tr>';
                   }
                   echo '</table><br><input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Update"></form><br><br>';
               } else {
                  echo "<br>You have no creatures in your wishlist.";
               }
           }
        } catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) { 
            throw $e; 
        } 

        // Close the connection to the database
        $conn->close();
        [/insert_php]
      </code>
    </center>
```

Comment: @Drew You were so good last time do you know what's up?

Comment: Can you simplify the write up? Are the images needed? Why not use parameterized queries everywhere?

Comment: @chris85 I will do just that. The parameterized queries didn't work for me 100% of the time. Because I couldn't figure it out I switched it to something I understood more and it was working just fine so I left it

Comment: It is open to SQL injections. What didn't work, maybe a similar issue?

Comment: @chris85 Updating isn't working. Everything else works. And it only doesn't work after a certain amount of creatures are added to the wishlist

Comment: Are there errors when it fails?

Comment: @chris85 Nope it just refreshes the page instead of updating the information.It looks like there is a limit around 165

Comment: I guess it is at least 30 minutes of someone's time end-to-end. I turned on error reporting last time. You had typos in the form submit. A typo on an array name. Etc. Ramraider and I both went with bound parameters.

Comment: @Drew The issue I'm having now is that is works most of the time. I am not getting any errors, but that it is stopping working when a wishlist gets to the size of about 165

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that my server could not handle the number of form entries on the page. I setup pagination and everything seemed good from then on!